# Warning: 'chart.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: optimization, dependencies, warnings, amd, commonjs

ng2-charts.js depends on 'chart.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Add in angular.json
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["chart.js"],

Comment: This only suppresses the warning, it does not magically solve its underlying cause!

Comment: So how to solve this issue ? as this answer will just help to get rid of the message and will just hide it !

Comment: You load all library and Angular shows warning about this. ChartJs should solve this problem (i.e. with Tree Shake). There is no solution on Angular side. So this answer is best answer.

Comment: Only solution is to update library to remove dependency...Except if library's author doing it, good luck on your side...

Comment: Property allowedCommonJsDependencies is not allowed.